# Regex to find common letters between two strings

Tags: regex, groovy

I've been searching on Google for a few hours and got a partial solution.

I'm new to both Groovy and regular expressions. I've used regex sporadically over the years, but I am far from comfortable with it.

I've got a simple game that checks how many letters you have in common with a hidden word.

For simplicity's sake, let's say the word is "pan" and the person types "can".

I want the result of the regex to give me "an".

Right now, I've got this partly working by doing this (in Groovy):

```
// Where "guess" is the user's try and "word" is the word they need to guess.
def expr = "[$word]"
def result = guess.find(expr)
```

The result string contains only the first matching letter. Anyone have any more elegant solutions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't look like a good use-case for regular expressions.

Comment: [Longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)

Comment: What's your definition of "having letters in common"? Do they need to be in the same position or anywhere in the word? Do they have to be in the right order?

Comment: @RobertB: When I reread the question, it doesn't seem to be longest common substring problem.

Comment: What if the word is `banana`, and they guess `can`?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @Phillipp letters in common would for example, if the user typed "pan" and the clue word is "pin" I would like to get the result "pn". I've tried this on http://www.regextester.com/index2.html and the site does show the result I want, it just doesn't show the regex for it. It even highlights in colour the matching and non-matching letters.

Comment: @tim_yates then I would want "an" as the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the two strings are s1 and s2
now to find the common string do:

```
commonString=s1.replaceAll("[^"+s2+"]","");
```

and if your word contain meta-character then
first do:

```
Pattern.quote(s2);
```

and then

```
commonString=s1.replaceAll("[^"+s2+"]","");
```

Comment: Thanks @Ranjit tried that and it works too. Still mulling over whether which approach is more elegant, this or the "findAll" above.

Comment: Thanks @Ranjt both ideas worked, this one appeals because my simple understanding of regex can handle it!

Answer (score 3):

I think this is no use case for a regex. You'll have to take care of things like not leting the user guess automatically if he enters `.*` or the like.

Typical collection work is better suited for this task IMO. One solution would be to find the intersection of both words treating them as sets of characters:

```
(word as Set).intersect(guess as Set).join()
```

Or filtering the guess' characters that appear in the secret word:

```
guess.findAll { word.contains(it) }.unique().join()
```

Comment: Thanks @epidemian, still getting to grips with Groovy, but this looks very cool.

Comment: It's possible to find repeating substrings using [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), but then you would need to combine the two strings into one string.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
guess.findAll( /[$word]/ ).join()
```

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates tried that and it works. Could you explain the "join" part? I think I get the regex, but I'm not sure why the slashes produce the result, my understanding was [$word] would do the same?